# Build NSIS script for java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, nsis

I have installed NSIS plugin in my eclipse.I have only one java project in my eclipse workspace.Using this plugin i need to create .nsi file.I searched in google but I couldnot get.Any one please help me, What step I need to follow to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EclipseNSIS user guide](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/help/index.html) shows in great detail, how to create your own installer script. It is also available directly on your machine in your Eclipse help.

The [script wizard](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/help/eclipsensis/wizard.html) should give you a quick start.

Comment: Thank you.I have followed this stepts.I cant able to create whole project.It also applicable java project?